# Cómo linkear estas librerías en QT y XMPP

Tags: qt, xmpp

¿Cómo puedo linkear esta librerías al proyecto xmpp:

- gdi32.lib
- comdlg32.lib
- oleaut32.lib
- imm32.lib
- winmm.lib
- winspool.lib
- ws2_32.lib
- ole32.lib
- user32.lib
- advapi32.lib
- msimg32.lib
- shell32.lib
- kernel32.lib
- uuid.lib

Errores:

```
>  link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
> /VERSION:0.9 /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:qxmpp_d0.dll
> @C:\Users\moh\AppData\Local\Temp\qxmpp_d0.dll.5596.60859.jom   
> Creando biblioteca qxmpp_d0.lib y objeto qxmpp_d0.exp
> libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2019: sÝmbolo externo
> __imp__CreateCompatibleBitmap@12 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la funci¾n _readscreen libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj) :
> error LNK2019: sÝmbolo externo __imp__DeleteObject@4 sin resolver al
> que se hace referencia en la funci¾n _readscreen
> libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2019: sÝmbolo externo
> __imp__GetDeviceCaps@8 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la funci¾n _readscreen libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2019:
> sÝmbolo externo __imp__GetDIBits@28 sin resolver al que se hace
> referencia en la funci¾n _readscreen libeay32.lib(rand_win.obj) :
> error LNK2019: sÝmbolo externo __imp__GetObjectA@12 sin resolver al
> que se hace referencia en la funci¾n _readscreen qxmpp_d0.dll : fatal
> error LNK1120: 5 externos sin resolver jom:
> C:\Users\moh\Desktop\qxmpp-master\src\Makefile.Debug [qxmpp_d0.dll]
> Error 1120 jom: C:\Users\moh\Desktop\qxmpp-master\src\Makefile [debug]
> Error 2 jom: C:\Users
```

Como podría gracias

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta en Inglés. Debería ir en http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Lo pongo en español

Comment: Si da igual que lo ponga en stackoverflow nadie me contesta igualmente

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo, no sé si es demasiado tarde pero te comento. Estas intentando integrar librerías estáticas del propio sistema operativo, conocidas como "standard Windows library".

Este tipo de librerías se integran directamente sin la necesidad de añadir el directorio con todas las cabeceras como pasa con las librerías dinámicas.

En tu fichero .pro debes de escribir:

```
LIBS += -luser32
LIBS += -lshell32
.... así con todas ...
```

En cualquier caso el proceso más genérico es el siguiente:

```
LIBS += -L/path/ -nombre
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.